# How to limit string field by words not characters in Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My Documents looks like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e41877df4cebbeaebec5146"),
   "Paragraph" : "My Name is John Smith.I am learning MongoDB database"
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e4187d7f4cebbeaebec5147"),
   "Paragraph" : "David Miller is a good student and learning Spring and Hibernate Framework."
}
```

I want to limit Paragraph field text to 5 words like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e41877df4cebbeaebec5146"),
   "Paragraph" : "My Name is John Smith."
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e4187d7f4cebbeaebec5147"),
   "Paragraph" : "David Miller is a good"
}
```

Comment: You mean as an aggregation match or in the creation? Would love to get some code references and attempts

Comment: @EldarB. Aggregation

Comment: @EldarB. I am using Paragraph: { $substr: [ "$Paragraph", 0, 10] } but it's working with characters not words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `$split`, `$slice` and `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      Paragraph: {$reduce: {
          input: {$slice: [{$split: ["$Paragraph", " "]}, 5]},
          initialValue: "",
          in: {$concat: ["$$value", {$concat: ["$$this", " "]}]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      Paragraph: {
        $substr: ["$Paragraph", 0, {$subtract: [{$strLenCP: "$Paragraph"}, 1]}]
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UztzdhyDX9m)

Comment: Have to use proper spacing with it and it's gonna work. thanks

Comment: By spacing I means in paragraph "My Name is John Smith.I am learning MongoDB database" currently resulting "My Name is John Smith.I" for 5 words. I have to fix spacing of my paragraph. It's working fine with proper paragraph spacing.